# react-dom.development.js:14997 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
Profile.jsx
```

import React from 'react'
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
import "./Profile.css"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { ProfilePicture } from '../App'

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
display: flex;
background-color: black;
height: 100vh;

justify-content: center;

`
const Container = styled.div`
background-color: gray;
width: 50%;

`
const Status = styled.div`
display: flex;
font-size: 15px;
`

const H4 = styled.h4`
padding: 10px;

`
export function Profile (){
 const userdata = React.useContext(ProfilePicture)
    const pathname = window.location.pathname
    const[data,setData] = useState([])
    const [user,isUser] = useState(false)
    const[owner,isOwner] = useState(false)

  let username = pathname.split("/")[1]

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/profile/getProfile', {
      "username":username
    })
    .then((res)=> {
        if (res.status == "405"){
            console.log("rab")
        }
        setData(res.data[0])
        isUser(true)
     
       
    }).catch((err)=> {
       
        isUser(false)
    })
    
  
    
  }, []);
  if (userdata.username == username){
    isOwner(true)
  }
  console.log(userdata.username)
  return (
<Wrapper>
<Container>

{owner ? console.log("Owner"):console.log("not Owner") }
    <div className='Profile'>
    <h2>{data.username}</h2>
   
<img className='ProfileImg' src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png' />
{user?<h2>{data.username}</h2>:<h2>No User Exists</h2>}
  
    <img  />
    <Status>
<H4>Followers</H4>
<H4>Following</H4>
</Status>
<H4>Posts</H4>
    </div>
    </Container>
    </Wrapper>

  )
}
```

console log

```
undefined
Profile.jsx:66 not Owner
Profile.jsx:63 undefined
Profile.jsx:66 not Owner
Profile.jsx:63 undefined
Profile.jsx:66 not Owner
Profile.jsx:63 undefined
Profile.jsx:66 not Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 not Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
Profile.jsx:63 a
Profile.jsx:66 Owner
```

how can i prevent this error?
or how can i wait for the state value to !== "undefined"

Comment: `if (userdata.username == username){ isOwner(true) }` - don't do this, it's most likely the cause of your infinite rerender.

Answer (score 0):

From the loops of it, you are stuck in an infinite `useEffect` loop.

This is likely caused by regardless of and response or error, function `isUser` is called. This means that the function will rerender and called `useEffect` over and over again each time the state of `user` changes.

To fix this, we can add a dependency to the `useEffect` call so that `useEffect` gets called only when `data` is called.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/profile/getProfile', {
      "username":username
    })
    .then((res)=> {
        if (res.status == "405"){
            console.log("rab");
        }
        setData(res.data[0])
        isUser(true)
    }).catch((err)=> {
        isUser(false)
    })
}, [data]);
```